# Error findAndModify using in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having tough time using `findAndModify`. Here is my code & error :-

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    incr: Number,
    practicename: String,
    basicinformation: [
        {
            recordno: String,
            firstname: String,
            middlename: String,
            lastname: String,
            gender: String,
            dateofbirth: Date,
            dateofdeath: Date,
            socialsecurityno: String,
            status: String,
            updateddate: Date,
            updatedby: String
        }
    ],

userSchema.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, doc, options, callback) {
    return this.collection.findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback);
}
```

Lib/Controller

```
var query = {
        update: { $inc: { incr: 1 } },
        upsert: true
    };

    User.findAndModify(query, function (err, users) {
        if (err) return res.send(500)
        if (!err) console.log(users)
    });
```

Error :-

```
Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descendi
ng)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]
    at Object.exports.formattedOrderClause (D:\Projects\project1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\utils.js:41:1
1)
    at Collection.findAndModify (D:\Projects\project1
```

Comment: You do realize you have changed the default signature for this method so you not? You do not need to declare the `statics` as you have. Use the default method and have another look at the documentation as your arguments are wrong.

Comment: when i use it directly without statistics, i get TypeError :- `TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'findAndModify'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, get rid of this code as you do not need it and you are actually defining a "static" signature that you are not even using:

```
userSchema.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, doc, options, callback) {
    return this.collection.findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback);
}
```

You should have a declaration for your `User` model that is something like this:

```
var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );
```

Now let's look at the usage of the mongoose method [**`.findOneAndUpdate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) in long form:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: userid },                 // this is what "query" means
    { "$inc": { "incr": 1 } },       // this is what "update" means
    { "upsert": true },              // this is what "options" means
    function(err,user) {
```

You were trying to use the "native" collection method rather than the same that already exists using Mongoose. Also this shows the correct arguments that  that need to be passed to this method that are further explained in the documentation link provided.

Also see [**`.findByIdAndUpdate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) and other methods that are basic variations of the .findAndModify()` method.

Comment: When i run the above code, the record does't get incremented....I can see `POST /api/users/create 500 10ms - 21b` in my CMD...!

Comment: @Anup `userid` in my example is what you need to pass in. Have you cast this to an `ObjectId`? You will need to if you are getting this as part of POST data. The `user` in the callback is the modified document by default.

Comment: The above code works but when i check in database, the value doesn't get incremented....in console i get this `{ _id: 538c43bf7b412a14637605ec, userrecordno: 13 }`

Comment: @Anup You did not read the comment above. You need to cast to an ObjectId. It is not "working" because you are comparing and ObjectId to a string.

Comment: Thanks for all the help....I just restarted Robomongo...Its working perfectly...!

Answer (score 1):

you can try mongoose [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) method instead

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate( id, { $set: {name: 'xyz'}} , { new:true}, function(err,result) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.warn(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

the option `new:true` returns the updated document, else the old unupdated document